# Scala pattern matching for type

Tags: scala, functional-programming, pattern-matching

I've written the following code:

```
array(0).getClass match {
  case Int.getClass =>
    byeBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(4 * array.length)

  case Long.getClass =>
    ByteBuffer.allocate(8 * array.length)

  case Float.getClass =>
    ByteBuffer.allocate(4 * array.length)

  case Double.getClass =>
    ByteBuffer.allocate(8 * array.length)

  case Boolean.getClass =>
    ByteBuffer.allocate(1 * array.length)
```

However the overuse of `getClass` feels clumsy to me.

Is there a nicer way to write it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can omit the `getClass` and use the type operator (`:`):

```
val byteBuffer = array(0) match {
  case _: Int =>
    ByteBuffer.allocate(4 * array.length)
  case _: Long =>
    ByteBuffer.allocate(8 * array.length)
  case _: Float =>
    ByteBuffer.allocate(4 * array.length)
  case _: Double =>
    ByteBuffer.allocate(8 * array.length)
  case _: Boolean =>
    ByteBuffer.allocate(1 * array.length)
}
```

Also notice, that `match` is an expression in Scala, so you can move `byteBuffer` outside and assign the result to it. Such functional approach will make it cleaner and allow us to avoid reasigning to `var` and use `val` instead.

If you want to use the variable you're matching type against, then you can simply write for example `l: Long` and use the variable of type `Long` by the name `l`.

Comment: `array.getClass.getComponentType`. If the array is empty, etc.

Comment: Or even better use a **typeclass** instead, since matching for types _(classes actually)_ is not exhaustive and Amy fail for complex types.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comments. Of course I agree with both checking for emptiness in the simple version and typeclasses. But using typeclasses although very elegant and clean, would mean rewriting the code completely, I don't know if OP wants to dive into more complex topics (pattern matching is relatively easy)

Comment: I would actually love to convert it into a type class. Could you add to your answer a version with a type class please?

Comment: I've opened a new question for that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61443874/convert-type-pattern-maching-to-type-class

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez please take a look as well in my new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61443874/convert-type-pattern-maching-to-type-class