# Convert type pattern maching to type class

Tags: scala, functional-programming, pattern-matching, typeclass

I have the following code:

```
val byteBuffer = array(0) match {
  case _: Int =>
    ByteBuffer.allocate(4 * array.length)
  case _: Long =>
    ByteBuffer.allocate(8 * array.length)
  case _: Float =>
    ByteBuffer.allocate(4 * array.length)
  case _: Double =>
    ByteBuffer.allocate(8 * array.length)
  case _: Boolean =>
    ByteBuffer.allocate(1 * array.length)
}
```

How can I convert it to use type class?

**Edit:**

I was asked what the type of the array is. It's complicated. The array is declared like that:

```
val array = obj.asInstanceOf[mutable.WrappedArray[Any]].array
```

obj is a parameter that the function accepts:

```
val createBuffer = (obj: Any, dType: DataType) => dType match {
```

The function is called here:

```
val byteBuffer: Option[ByteBuffer] = createBuffer(row.get(i), types(i))
```

row is a Spark DataFrame row.

Comment: What is the type of your `array`?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov it's dynamic. This is exactly why I have a switch case here.

Comment: If it's an `Array[AnyRef]`, I don't see how a typeclass would be a good fit here.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I've editted my question

Comment: Sometimes a typeclass isn't a good fit, especially when you have no control over types and have to conform to third parties like Spark.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A **typeclass** would look like this:

```
trait ByteSize[T] {
  def tSize: Int
}

object ByteSize {
  implicit final val IntByteSize: ByteSize[Int] =
    new ByteSize[Int] {
      override final val tSize: Int = 4
    }

  implicit final val LongByteSize: ByteSize[Long] =
    new ByteSize[Long] {
      override final val tSize: Int = 8
    }

  // Other instances.
}

object syntax {
  object bytes {
    implicit class ArrayOps[T](private val arr: Array[T]) extends AnyVal {
      final def allocateByteBuffer(implicit ev: ByteBuffer[T]): ByteBuffer =
        ByteBuffer.allocate(ev.tSize * array.length)
    }
  }
}
```

Which you can use like:

```
import syntax.bytes._

val arr: Array[Int] = ???

val byteBuffer = arr.allocateByteBuffer
```

You may even provide more useful extension methods, like instead of just allocating the **ByteBuffer**, you can fill it directly.

---

*Note, remember **typclasses** are type driven, thus are resolved at compile time.
If you do not know the type of your array, then that pattern match is the best you can do.*
*You may want to see if you can refactor your code so it becomes more strongly types, since **Any**, in general, is considered a code smell. But, if you can't or it is too much work for the benefits, then typeclasses are simply the wrong tool for the job.*

Comment: Do I understand this correctly, that this will not work for `Array[Any]`, because the type cannot be infered at compile time? (Of course unless we provide a type class instance for `Any`.)

Comment: @Andronicus Well providing an instance for **Any** would end up doing something similar to that match so it won't provide any improvement and would imply all the boilerplate of a typeclass, so that would be the worst of both worlds. - So yes, this won't work for **Any** / **AnyRef**.